# Can i install Windows Phone SDK 8.0 on Windows 8 PRO 32 bit computer?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sdk, windows-phone-8, x86, 64-bit

I am new to apps development.I have a nokia lumia phone and i wanted to develop apps so i downloaded sdk 8.0 and when i was installing it it said i need 64 bit windows 8.And i have no 64 bit machine.So is there a way to install it on 32 bit computer.I wonder why microsoft has set up so high requirements they already have less apps and if they continue these requirments then who the hell will want to develop the apps for it.I want to develop apps because i have windows phone so guys please help me.I knpw that it is impossible to install it but i cant currently buy 64 bit machine so does that mean i should not develop apps for it or is there a way??

Comment: Windows Phone 8 SDK requires Hyper-V. Hyper-V requires a x64 bit machine. So the simple answer is no.

Comment: You can still use the Windows Phone 7.x SDK (and those apps will also work on Windows Phone 8 devices) on x86 architecture; it'll also allow you to target a slightly bigger market, until you get hold of a Hyper-H capable machine.

Answer (score 2):

From the official download page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471.

```
    Supported operating systems: Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro

        Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
        Hardware:
            4 GB of free hard disk space
            4 GB RAM
            64-bit (x64) CPU
        Windows Phone 8 Emulator:
            Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
            Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

    If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements, but does
            meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator, the Windows Phone SDK 8.0
            will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8 Emulator will not function and
            you will not be able to deploy or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.
```

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. The Requirements of Windows SDK 8.0 id Windows 8 64-bit OS.  Because, as Alaa Said `Windows Phone 8 SDK requires Hyper-V. Hyper-V requires a x64 bit machine.`

If you were using, 32-bit OS. Don't format it. Just install 64-bit OS in another drive and use that OS for Windows SDK 8.0.

Now, I think your doubts were solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool:

```
Supported Operating System
```

Windows 7, Windows Vista
Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions except Starter Edition
Windows 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions except Starter Edition

Installation requires 3 GB of free disk space on the system drive.
2 GB RAM
Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13890

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Download the iso file, extract it, then change the `.exe` file with [this program](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422751).

Change your computer's date to September 1st and install it.

Application deployment will give an error when you deploy -- use wpv xap deployer 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

WP8 SDK works in windows 7 Pro x86 with this mod from xda. However, I think you need MS Visual studio express 2010 for WP installed before WP8 sdk installation.